# When opening through filedialog in tkinter is there a way that pictures would stay if opened one by one?

Tags: tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have been just experimenting with tkinter's filedialog. What I know is that images have to be a global variable somehow to become visible. Which is alright as within modules you can use the word "global" so that the variable would be able to be accessed outside of the function as well and hence be visualized, but unfortunately with askopenfilename it updates the global variable hence if you open pictures one by one the previous one always disappears.
My question is how can I implement it in my code that my function would create global variables so that my images would always be visible.
Or is there another way I could do it? I know about that I can open more files at once and they will all be loaded and be visualized but **my question is strictly about opening images one by one**.

I tried to mess with my functions a little and try to make it work somehow that's why my code is a bit more split... But I hope someone out there can help me about this issue!

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()

gallery_frame = tk.Frame(root)
gallery_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

pic_counter = [0, 0]


def pic_counter_checker():
    pic_counter[0] += 1
    if pic_counter[0] % 3 == 0:
        pic_counter[0] = 0
        pic_counter[1] += 1


files_list = []


def pic_factory():
    global img
    for pic in files_list:
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(pic))
        img_label = tk.Label(gallery_frame, image=img)
        img_label.grid(row=pic_counter[1], column=pic_counter[0])


def open_picture():
    dir_path = "C:/Users/Marci/PycharmProjects/Images"
    filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=dir_path, title="Open your file")
    files_list.append(filename)
    name_label = tk.Label(gallery_frame, text=filename)
    name_label.grid(row=pic_counter[1], column=pic_counter[0])
    pic_factory()
    pic_counter_checker()
    print(files_list)


lab1 = tk.Label(root, text="Open your file to add to the gallery")
lab1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="Open file", command=open_picture)
btn1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

The original way obviously did not work as the global variable kept getting updated and lost its visuals after each new file that has been opened. So I thought maybe if I create a function for a loop and assign inside a global variable (see: pic_factory()) somehow that "globalness" could be inherited but of course it was stupid and I did not have my hopes up so much either, but I thought it's might worth a try... since this is a weird phenomenon already that an image must be a global variable in order to be visualized.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Save the images to a list or dictionary.

Comment: You can use an attribute of a label to store the reference of the image instead of a global variable, for example `img_label.image = img`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an attribute of the created label instead of global variable to store the reference of the image:

```py
def pic_factory():
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=files_list[-1])
    img_label = tk.Label(gallery_frame, image=img)
    img_label.grid(row=pic_counter[1], column=pic_counter[0])
    img_label.image = img  # use an attribute to store the reference of image
```

Note that you should not use a for loop inside `pic_factory()`.

---

Actually you can combine `name_label` and `img_label` into one label:

```py
def pic_factory():
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=files_list[-1])
    # show both filename and image in same label
    img_label = tk.Label(gallery_frame, image=img, text=files_list[-1], compound="top")
    img_label.grid(row=pic_counter[1], column=pic_counter[0])
    img_label.image = img  # use an attribute to store the reference of image


def open_picture():
    dir_path = "images"
    filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=dir_path, title="Open your file")
    files_list.append(filename)
    #name_label = tk.Label(gallery_frame, text=filename)
    #name_label.grid(row=pic_counter[1], column=pic_counter[0])
    pic_factory()
    pic_counter_checker()
    print(files_list)
```